# Injecting/merging nested arrays with C#/LINQ

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, linq

I currently have the following JSON structure:

```
[
  {
    "parent1": "parent",
    "parentnested1": [
      {
        "nestedvalue1": "example1"
      },
      {
        "nestedvalue1": "example2"
      }
    ],
    "parentnested2": [
      {
        "nestedvalue2": "example1"
      },
      {
        "nestedvalue2": "example2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent2": "parent",
    "parentnested1": [
      {
        "nestedvalue1": "example1"
      },
      {
        "nestedvalue1": "example2"
      }
    ],
    "parentnested2": [
      {
        "nestedvalue2": "example1"
      },
      {
        "nestedvalue2": "example2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Using entity framework/LINQ/C# i need to return the parentnested1 array with the parentnested2 array nested inside of it:

```
[
  {
    "parent1": "parent",
    "parentnested1": [
      {
        "nestedvalue1": "example1",
        "parentnested2": [
          {
            "nestedvalue2": "example1"
          },
          {
            "nestedvalue2": "example2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "nestedvalue1": "example2",
        "parentnested2": [
          {
            "nestedvalue2": "example1"
          },
          {
            "nestedvalue2": "example2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "parent2": "parent",
    "parentnested1": [
      {
        "nestedvalue1": "example1",
        "parentnested2": [
          {
            "nestedvalue2": "example1"
          },
          {
            "nestedvalue2": "example2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "nestedvalue1": "example2",
        "parentnested2": [
          {
            "nestedvalue2": "example1"
          },
          {
            "nestedvalue2": "example2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can i achieve this/whats the cleanest way to do this?

Do I need to get both nested arrays and then somehow 'inject' one array into the other?

Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries you can use to deseriealize and manipulate Json structure. Newtonsoft (Json.Net) is one of them.

```
string json = "[{...";//you can get the json from a file or depending on the app logic
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
jsonObj["parentnested1"]="...";//do your modificaitons
//you can use the equivalent of xpath as well (SelectToken) and work with it
string data = (string)o.SelectToken("parentnested1[0]");
string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
json = output;
```